# Riemann extension theorem with $Re(g)$ bounded

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $D$ be an open subset of the complex plane,  a point $a$ of  $D$ and $g$ a holomorphic function defined on the set $D$ \ ${a}$,if $Re(g)$ is bounded from above,how to show that $g$ can extends to $D$. I want to use Riemann extension Theorem but can't start. I think $a$ is a removable singularity in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Begin by introducing $f=e^g$. Details are below.

---

The function $|f|=e^{\operatorname{Re} g}$ is bounded. By the Riemann extension theorem, $f$ has a holomorphic extension to $D$.  If $f(a)\ne 0$, then we can take a holomorphic branch of $\log f$ in a neighborhood of $a$ and observe that $\log f - g$ is constant (a multiple of $2\pi i$). This provides an extension of $g$.

If $f(a)=0$, write $f(z)=(z-a)^m F(z)$ where $F(a)\ne 0$. Now $\log F$ has a holomorphic branch in a neighborhood of $a$. Hence, $\log F-g$ is holomorphic in a punctured neighborhood of $a$. But locally in this neighborhood, $\log F-\log g = - m\log (z-a)$ up to a multiple of $2\pi i$. This is a contradiction because $m\log (z-a)$ does not have a single-valued holomorphic branch in a  punctured neighborhood of $a$.